# Pure JS - eventlistener mouseover select options display images based on hover

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mouseover

I need to display an image in a div based on the hover location of the mouse within a dropdown menu.  Here's what I have so far.  It only works for the FIRST option in the select.  Any help is appreciated! :-)

JS:

```
document.getElementById("configuration").addEventListener("mouseover",configurationchange); 
function configurationchange(e){
    var configurationvalue = e.target.value;
    fddisp_image2(configurationvalue); /* this function displays the image in div with innerhtml */
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="configuration" id="configuration">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="Square/Rect.">Square/Rectangular</option>
    <option value="Oval">Oval</option>
    <option value="Round">Round</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The current value of a select field does not change just because you _hover_ over an option.

Comment: Are you more interested in the position (x,y) of the cursor? Or the `option` that it's hovering over in the dropdown? It may help if you could add a bit more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks rob.  I need the select "option" value that the mouse is currently hovering over.  Then I pass that value to a div using innerHTML which works but only for the first option.  Subsequent hovers do not work with the current code.

Comment: BTW - If I change the select to a "multiple" it works.

Comment: However, select "multiple" is not what is required for this project.  We need a traditional dropdown menu.